# Dynamic hyperlink to be added to the Power BI report

Tags: powerbi

Have a situation to use dynamic link upon slicer selection in power BI.

Dynamic Link upon User Slicer Selection in Power BI. I have a situation to select the date slicer and am using the  measure to build but I don't need the &id= which appears in my link as well which is not part of my link. My Table'[My ID] as date field.

My URL = "http://www.example.com/query&id=" & CONCATENATEX ( VALUES ( 'My Table'[My ID] ), 'My Table'[My ID], "&id=", 'My Table'[My ID], ASC )

While the URL obtained from the column is properly displayed and used as an hyperlink, the URL includes all IDs (not only the selected ones). Contrarily, the URL from the measure is just the right one (only selected IDs in URL) but it can not be displayed nor used as an hyperlink.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> the URL from the measure is just the right one (only selected IDs in URL) but it can not be displayed nor used as an hyperlin

Sure it can.  Just change the "Data category" of the measure to "Web URL" and display it on a Table or Matrix visual.

Answer (score 0):

There no longer seems to be an ability to set a "Data Category". There is only the option to set the "data type", under which there is no "Web URL" option.

Comment: This is incorrect. If you click on a measure and look in `Measure tools` in the top ribbon, you can select `Web URL` as data category, given that the format is `Text`. (Checked on Version: 2.123.684.0 64-bit (november 2023))